# How to open a Settings charm flyout programmatically using callisto library

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have implemented a file picker inside a settings flyout. When i click on the button the filepicker window is opened and after choosing the file it goes back to the app screen but the settings flyout in which the file picker button was there is closed. I want the settings flyout to be open during and after the file selection. Basically i want something like the isLightDismissEnabled property for this settings flyout, but i couldnt find any such property in callisto.controls.SettingsFlyout. Can anyone tell me how to set the isLightDismissEnabled property of a settinsg charm flyout or in general how to keep the flyout open?

In my App.xaml.cs i have added a custom flyout to the main settings charm flyout like this -

```
 AppSettings.Current.AddCommand<AlarmSettingsPaneView>("Alarm", Callisto.Controls.SettingsFlyout.SettingsFlyoutWidth.Narrow);
```

And in my AlarmSettingsPaneView i have this combo selection changed function which enables this file picker.

```
private async void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {


        if ((sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem.ToString() == "Custom")
        {
            FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
            openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
            openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.MusicLibrary;
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wma");

            StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
            if (file != null)
            {
                // Application now has read/write access to the picked file
                CustomSound.Text = file.Name;

            }
            else
            {
                CustomSound.Text = "Operation cancelled.";
            }
        }

    }
```

So how can i keep this AlarmSettingsPaneView which is a custom settings flyout to be open after my file is selected?

Answer (score 2):

The SettingsFlyout in Callisto is a regular control that uses a popup in its implementation. Since this popup is set as light-dismissable with no way to change that, you will have to download Callisto's source code and change that value yourself.

You can also appeal to its developers to make that property publicly accessible. It would be beneficial in the long term.

Comment: I think what u said makes sense......it should work....But i have never done editing an existing package and using it again so i need ur help a bit here. Earlier i just added the package using nuget. Now i think the source code is here https://github.com/timheuer/callisto i have downloaded the source code and made the change i wanted. But its not getting build. It throws an error saying it cant find the callisto.dll file in the debug folder which i guess i should use to reference it in my app. Can anyone help me out here plz?

Comment: Indeed, you must remove the original package and reference. Then, you can "add an existing project" to your solution and select the Callisto project that you downloaded and modified.